# In Sitecore, when I publish my VS solution I get an error license key not found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8

In sitecore 8. when I publish my VS solution. I get an error like license key not found. while I have placed the license key of sitecore and of active commerce at proper folder i.e sandbox/data.Need help. Any suggestion?

Comment: I get error message "Required license is missing: Sitecore.Ecommerce".

Comment: Is the license key path correct in web.config? Is the correct value getting overwritten by your publishing profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this occur when the VS solution has the Web.config with the default /data value (or a hard-coded value) that is not valid for the local installation. If you used the Sitecore installer, it often updates the Web.config with the value for the Data folder that is applicable to that local installation.

Instead, you should be using a patch include to specify the data folder. Sitecore Instance Manager will do this for you when you use it to install.

In this way, the proper data folder for your installation will be preserved no matter how many times you deploy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes my VS soluon's web.config file had a different location for license key. when I corrected it,the issue is resolved.